# why commit records local file without staging it?

Tags: git, commit, stage

I am new to git and try to execute examples to understand the staging process.
I was reading many tutorials and my understanding was, that just the FileA that I have added before to the staging area (`git add FileA`) will be committed.
But this does not happen, instead the file from my workdir will be committed, that I changed once again local right after I added the FileA to the stage area and without adding my changes again to the staging area.

What I did:

**FileA**

with

```
row1
```

already added and committed for first time. Fine!

Afterwards I changed this file by adding another row, to become

```
row1
row2
```

Now I add it this file to stage by

```
git add FileA
```

Now again I change this FileA local to become

```
row1
row2
row3
```

`git status -s` is telling me, that this file has been modified

```
git status -s
MM FileA.txt
```

Well if I commit it now, I did expect from reading that only the changes that are
waiting in the stage-area are being committed and not the changes on my workdir.
But this did not happen. Instead the changes from my local workdir are committed, so that I have

```
row1
row2
row3
```

Does anybody know about the reason?

Comment: Why do you think that line3 has also been committed?

Comment: Cause I see it when I push it to git hub

Comment: What command did you use to commit your changes?

Comment: git commit -m "Blabla" FileA.txt

Comment: `git commit FileA.txt` commits the content of the file, not staged data. To commit only staged data the command should be just `git commit` without file names.

Comment: That's it, that was my misunderstanding. Thank you very much.